# Will Cyanogen 13 update to Lineage 14 and preserve apps, data etc?

Tags: cyanogenmod, lineageos

I have an S5 with TouchWiz (i.e. standard rom) I want to change, but I don't want to have to wipe and reinstall everything twice over.

There is a stable Cyanogen 13, and an experimental lineage 14, for my device. I don't want to install an experimental build.

If I install Cyan 13, will it be able to update to Lineage 14 when it becomes stable, without me having to reinstall everything? Or should I just wait till Lineage 14 becomes stable?

Comment: Going from stock to lineage/cm is not going to work. But if you want to go from cm13 to lineage 14 without wiping /data you must use experimental build of lineage (they will be out for limited time) so.

Comment: I know I have to start again at least once, my point is will I have to do it a second time when upgrading from stable cm 13 to (future) stable los 14?

Comment: From cm to lineage os you must wipe or use experimental build (they are made because of that). You can go from cm to lineage without wipe but that will probably cause many bugs if it even boot

Comment: OK, thanks. Looks like I'll have to wait for stable los.

Comment: Why wait? You still can't directly update to stable when it's out. The transition to LOS is a fundamental upgrade to database and other components.

Comment: Because i don't want to go from a stable build to an unstable one

Answer (score 3):

If you install CyanogenMod 13 then you cannot install lineage OS 14 without wiping the device.
If you install CyanogenMod 14 then you can directly install Linage OS 14 without wiping the device, but it is not guaranteed.
If you install CyanogenMod 13 then you may install Lineage OS 13 without wiping the device, but it is not guaranteed.

Lineage OS web site as more clarification.

http://lineageos.org/Update-and-Build-Prep/